# Video is not shown when returning to app

Tags: android, media-player

I have an activity with MediaPlayer and Button. The MediaPlayer contains a VideoView (using MediaPlayer.getDisplay(VideoView.getHolder())). When the button is pressed it pause the MediaPlayer and open a browser. returning to app suppose to continue the video (MediaPlayer .start())

When the activity started the video is plays and shown as expected but when i press the button and then I press return to the app the video is not shown but the sound is working.

Any idea how to make the video visible?

-Z

Comment: Also happens when onPause (pressing on home) is called.